# How to adjust the format of the date in PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I need to change the format of a date:

```
["Date"].ToLocalTime().ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

In this code where i have specified the columns. One of the is the column Date.

$Global:selectProperties=@("Date","00:00 - 07:59","08:00 - 16:59","17:00 - 23:59","Remark");
```

How can i specify that the column Date uses that format?

Gr. P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure about the global settings requirement in Sharepoint, but you can certainly format the date the way you need in PowerShell using the dash -f format statement:

```
$mydate = get-date
$someday = @("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}","00:00 - 07:59","08:00 - 16:59","17:00 - 23:59","Remark") -f $mydate

write-host $someday
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of the date is controlled by:

- the preferences of the user
- the site settings
- column's settings: Normal format vs user friendly format

As a result, you can't force a date field to show dd-mm-yyyy instead of mm-dd-yyyy via PowerShell.

**Site Locale**

Navigate to the Site Settings > Regional Settings. This page contains a section called "Locale". This setting controls the date formats for fields on your site.

[image]

**List Settings > Date field**

Another place where you can have basic control of the date format for a specific field in a list:

[image]

Comment: Maybe i have explained it wrong :) I need to convert the date to the right format in Powershell : $Global:selectProperties=@(["Date"].ToLocalTime().ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),"00:00 - 07:59","08:00 - 16:59","17:00 - 23:59","Remark");

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase it a little, so that it's more clear, please?